# Can std::remove_pointer be used to remove all indirection from pointer type?

Tags: c++

Say that I have.. int, int*, int**, etc. Can I use std::remove_pointer or similar to get straight to type int? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can. Go try it.

Comment: Sorry I meant in a general way that doesn't depend on the level of indirection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yuppers.

```
template<typename T> struct remove_all {
    typedef T type;
};
template<typename T> struct remove_all<T*> {
    typedef typename remove_all<T>::type type;
};
```

`std::remove_pointer` itself isn't of that much use here.

Comment: I think you need additional specializations for top-level qualifiers, e.g. `T* const`.

Comment: I don't think so, but they are pretty easy to add.

Comment: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) and g++4.8 say you need them. (Yes, they're easy to add.)